# Why do my python program with while loop runs infinitely

Tags: python

This is the code given in official python documentation for printing down Fibonacci series.

I don’t understand why this code runs to infinity as the while loop condition is alright.

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print a,
        a, b = b, a + b

number = raw_input("What's the number you want to get Fibonacci series up to?")
fib(number)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing a string to `fib`, while `a` is an integer. In Python 2, *any* integer is less than *any* string.

```
>>> 1000000000000000000000000000000000 < ""
True
>>> 3 < "2"
True
```

Call your function with an integer instead:

```
fib(int(number))
```

If you were using Python 3, the attempt to compare a string and a number would simply raise a `TypeError`:

```
>>> "3" < 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Could you please explain how the print statement works in my code

Answer (score 1):

Raw_input gives a string so you compare a string with a int.